# How to use a single webhook for multiple messenger apps/bots?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing different chatbots for different fb pages but I only have one server to run them.

For the first chatbot I am using `https://mydomain/webhook` as webhook and everything works fine, all the messages are sent to the `443 port` and my program process them. Now I was wondering what should be the webhook for my second chatbot. My idea was to open a https connection on another port and use `https://mydomain/webhook:myport` as webhook so that each bot listen on a different port and each webhook points to them accordingly.

Unfortunately when I try to validate my webhook from the facebok developer platform I got a `404 not found` response. I also tried to use the same webhook on the same port (443) and I get `403 forbidden` response.

Comment: do you have any server running on that other port?

Comment: I found out my mistake, check my answer! @luschn Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why would you need to use different ports for each bot? When you have a web server running, you don’t make every browser connect on a different port either - they all use 80 or 443. Same thing here. And if you want to keep different bots independent of each other, then it would make much more sense to use different paths - `https://mydomain/webhook/bot1`, `https://mydomain/webhook/bot2`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the exact same webhook, same port and all, for multiple facebook messenger bots. Each payload of messaging events sent to your webhook will be sorted into a list of pages that the messages are for. You can write code to handle each page's payload differently after it has hit your webhook.

Comment: I considered this option but I wanted to keep my bots "indipendent" between each other. E.g. if one bots crash i don't want all the rest of them to crash with it. Thanks for the suggestion, this should actually be the accepted answer for my question even if i solved my problem in a different way.

Comment: A good point. Are you running these bots under the same server though? More fault tolerant would be separating the bots onto different processes, but I think you've got the right idea here.

Curious, are you using a bot framework, if so, which?

Comment: You could use one process (the server) to receive your payloads at the webhook, then dispatch the JSON payload to specific processes (bots) to handle that page's messages.

Answer (score 1):

My error was to add the port number after "/webhook" while the port number should go after the ip address "https://mydomain". In case anyone else was wondering, yes you can use the same webhook for different messenger apps, just use different ports.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive your response in 443 and then redirect to your specified port by using proxy pass in your server's conf.

```
    server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mydomain/webhook2;

    location /{
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:yourportname;
         }
    }
```